sequlize id autoincremental sin ser primary key
con sequelize tengo este modelo:
const User = sequelize.define(
  "users",
  {
    id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      autoIncrement: true,
    },
    email: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      primaryKey: true,
    },    
);

se puede definir en el modelo un autoincremental sin que sea primaryKey?
MySQL me da este error: code: 'ER_WRONG_AUTO_KEY',
    errno: 1075,
    sqlState: '42000',
    sqlMessage: 'Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key'

Gracias.

Y porque querrias que tu id unico, no nulo, automatico no fuera primarykey?

¿No sería mejor definir email como unique?

email está como unique, es el primary key de la tabla, era una duda, por que tengo tablas, por ejemplo, el detalle de una factura que puede tener de uno a muchas filas y el id suele ser una combinación de mas de un campo. Y era para tener un id único para facilitar la eliminación, o actualización.
